# How to cache query results in django and use it?

Tags: django, django-cache

I have a small request, the data from which is transferred to `<select>`. I use a paginator and this selector makes a request every page.So I want to cache it and try to update every 10 minutes, for example.How do I save a cache and how do I pass it to a template so that the selector works?

**views.py**

```
contractors = Contractors.objects.values_list('name', flat='True')
```

**HTML-code**

```
<select name="contractorName" class="form-control" id="id_contractorName">
<option value="" selected=""></option>
{% for contractor in contractors %}
<option value="{{ contractor }}">{{ contractor }}</option>
{% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Comment: You cannot cache the queries directly, although you can store small temporary values in settings.py or create a static map if your data in each case remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can do that based on [**`django cache framework`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching). 
Here is an example on how you can make a [**`template fragment`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) cache:

```
{% load cache %}

{% cache 600 contractors %}
    <select name="contractorName" class="form-control" id="id_contractorName">
    <option value="" selected=""></option>
    {% for contractor in contractors %}
    <option value="{{ contractor }}">{{ contractor }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endcache %}
```

Or you can also use [**`low level caching API`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) from django:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

...

contractors = cache.get('contractors')
if not contractors:
     contractors = list(Contractors.objects.values_list('name', flat='True'))
     cache.set('contractors', contractors, 600)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use django-cachalot for this. It caches data served and invalidates the cache as soon as the data changes.

https://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html